# how to make submit form button submit form values to database and change liquid slider panel?

Tags: jquery, mysql

i want it to submit the values in the form and i want it to cross link it to liquid slider so it changes the panel when it is clicked

this is the submit button

```
<input name = "submit" type="submit" class="submit1 tb10" value="Sign - Up" />
```

when i do this it changes the panel but it doesn't submit the data

```
<input name = "submit" type="submit" class="submit1 tb10" value="Sign - Up" href="#3" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id"/>
```

Comment: many sliders have external methods you can call in your code to change panels... post link to the docs for slider you are using. ALso is form submitted by ajax? Post ajax code

Comment: im using php but it changes the slide but it doesnt submit the data to the  database then when its just the submit button without trying to change the panel it submits the values to the database
this is the jquery source im using http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/

Comment: if you are submitting form through default browser method, page will reload so changing panel would require cookie, or url parsing or javscript variable inserted at server

Comment: yeah im doing the default how do i do it the way your saying? the javascript way would be good.

Comment: simplest to implement is to load page with hash in URL and set the `hashlinking` option in slider. See the first part of docs found below examples and tutorials on link you provided

Comment: idk how to do that lol i enabled he hashlinking but it just submits the values to the  database

Comment: form will load page based on `action` attribute of form. Remove any code related to slider within form elements. Make sure `action` URL that form redirects to has the hash required for slider

Comment: well the url doenst change even the form is submitted it does this

Comment: hard to follow without seeing live demo, and being able to inspect in browser console

Comment: if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
            $id = mysql_insert_id();
   
                               mkdir('members/'.$id,0755);

Comment: would you like me to do a screen cast so you could see it

Comment: https://secure.join.me/475-039-281 go to this website and you could see my screen

Comment: you will be able to see my screen live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set panels conditionally in the  [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) with a click event as follows...

Then you use a jQuery click event...

```
$('.submit1').on('click', function() {

    // Store the slider as an object
    var sliderObject = $.data( $('#slider-id')[0], 'liquidSlider');

    // n is the tab you want to switch to.
    sliderObject.currentTab(n);
});
```

If the page reloads, then you need to use hashlinking, as suggested by  charlietfl